# Atrapado en el try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

Al pulsar un botón de mi programa siempre queda atrapado en el  `catch`

El error que me da al ejecutar el programa es el siguiente

```
E/editarcontacto: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.victor.miscompaneros.editarcontacto.metodo_editar2(editarcontacto.java:138)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

El error me salta en la linea:

```
contacto.contactos.add(contacto);
```

**editarcontacto.java**

```
public class editarcontacto extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4, campo5, campo6, campo7, campo8, advertencia1;
    Integer telefono;
    String nombre,papellido,sapellido,direccion,poblacion;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;
    ImageView foto_gallery;
    Button boton1;
    LocalDate fechanacimiento;
    TableLayout lista;

    TableRow tabla2,tabla3,tabla4,tabla5,tabla6,tabla7,tabla8,tabla9;

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editarcontacto);

        //se asigna el campo de texto a la id que deseamos
        campo1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo1);
        campo2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo2);
        campo3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo3);
        campo4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo4);
        campo5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo5);
        campo6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo6);
        campo7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo7);
        campo8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        foto_gallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        boton1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        lista= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        //definimos las tablas

        tabla2= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla2);
        tabla3= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla3);
        tabla4= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla4);
        tabla5= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla5);
        tabla6= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla6);
        tabla7= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla7);
        tabla8= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla8);
        tabla9= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla9);

        advertencia1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        foto_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //Le llega la accion que debe tomar
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        int dato= extras.getInt("DATO");

        if (dato==1)
        {
            campo8.setText("AÑADIR CONTACTO");
            boton1.setText("Añadir");


        }

    }

    public void metodo_iniciar(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), menucontactos.class);
        intent.putExtra("DATO",1);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    public void metodo_editar2(View view) {

        //se añade el contacto

        nombre=campo1.getText().toString();
        papellido=campo2.getText().toString();
        sapellido=campo3.getText().toString();
        direccion=campo4.getText().toString();
        poblacion=campo6.getText().toString();
        try {
            telefono=Integer.parseInt(campo5.getText().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){

            advertencia1.setText("INTRODUZCA UN TELEFONO CORRECTO");
            advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        try {
            fechanacimiento = LocalDate.parse(campo7.getText());


            //convertimos la fecha tipo date en local date
            //fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

            LocalDate fechaactual = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(fechaactual.getYear(), fechanacimiento.getMonthValue(), fechanacimiento.getDayOfMonth());
            if (fechaactual.isAfter(birthday))
                birthday = birthday.plusYears(1);
            Period diff = Period.between(fechaactual, birthday);
            Contacto contacto = new Contacto(nombre, papellido, sapellido, direccion, poblacion, R.drawable.agenda, telefono, fechanacimiento);

            contacto.contactos.add(contacto);

            // se añade el array a la tabla del menu superior


            for (int i = 0; i < contacto.contactos.size(); i++) {


                String n = contacto.contactos.get(i).getNombre();
                LocalDate f = contacto.contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento();

                //metemos el nombre y el cumpleaños en sus determinadas columnas
                TextView textonombre = new TextView(this);
                TextView textofecha = new TextView(this);
                for (i = 0; i < contacto.contactos.size(); i++)
                    textonombre.setText(contacto.contactos.get(i).getNombre());

                //convertimos fecha en string para poder añadirla al texto
                String fechatexto = contacto.contactos.get(i).convertirfecha(contacto.contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento());

                textofecha.setText(fechatexto);

                //añadimos los atributos a sus respectivas columnas
                tabla2.addView(textonombre);
                tabla2.addView(textofecha);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            Logger.getLogger(editarcontacto.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
            advertencia1.setText("INTRODUZCA UNA FECHA CORRECTA");
            advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }


    private void openGallery(){
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            foto_gallery.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

**Archivo XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="EDITAR CONTACTO"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Nombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/campo1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/campo1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/apellido1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:text="Apellido 1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/campo3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/apellido2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/apellido2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/campo2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Telefono"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:text="Teléfono"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/campo5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/campo5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/apellido2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:text="Apellido 2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Fecha"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/campo1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Telefono"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Nombre" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Fecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="F.nacimiento"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/campo7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/campo7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Direccion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="Dirección"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/campo4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/campo3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foto"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:text="FOTO"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/campo6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/campo4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/campo6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/campo4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Poblacion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:text="Población"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/campo6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:onClick="metodo_editar2"
        android:text="Editar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:onClick="metodo_iniciar"
        android:text="Volver"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo1"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:hint="Introduce tu nombre aquí"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:hint="Introduce 1apellido aquí"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/apellido2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/campo3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/campo3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/campo1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo3"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="78dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="79dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="79dp"
        android:hint="Introduce 2apellido aquí"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/apellido2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/campo4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Direccion"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/apellido2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:hint="Introduce direccion aquí"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Telefono"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Direccion"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/apellido1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:digits="0123456789+"
        android:hint="Introduce telefono aquí"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Telefono"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/campo7" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:hint="Introduce población aquí"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/campo5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/campo5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campo7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
        android:hint="Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento aquí(yyyy-mm-dd)"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Fecha"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/campo5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/campo7"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="234dp"
        android:text="INTRODUCE UN NUMERO CORRECTO"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/campo7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

**Contacto.java**

    public class Contacto {

    String nombre, papellido,sapellido,direccion,poblacion;
    Integer telefono, foto;
    LocalDate fechanacimiento;
    ArrayList<Contacto> contactos;

    public Contacto(String nombre, String papellido, String sapellido, String direccion, String poblacion, int foto, Integer telefono, LocalDate fechanacimiento) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.papellido = papellido;
        this.sapellido = sapellido;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.poblacion = poblacion;
        this.foto = foto;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getPapellido() {
        return papellido;
    }

    public void setPapellido(String papellido) {
        this.papellido = papellido;
    }

    public String getSapellido() {
        return sapellido;
    }

    public void setSapellido(String sapellido) {
        this.sapellido = sapellido;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getPoblacion() {
        return poblacion;
    }

    public void setPoblacion(String poblacion) {
        this.poblacion = poblacion;
    }

    public Integer getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(Integer foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public Integer getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(Integer telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechanacimiento() {
        return fechanacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechanacimiento(LocalDate fechanacimiento) {
        this.fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

    public String convertirfecha(LocalDate fechanacimiento){

        //convertimos fecha(LocalDate) en Date
        Date date1 = Date.from(fechanacimiento.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        System.out.println("java.time.LocalDate -> java.util.Date: " + date1);

        //convertimos date en String

        String sDate2 = fechanacimiento.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        System.out.println("java.time.LocalDate -> String: " + sDate2);

        //devolvemos string
        return(sDate2);
    }

}
```

Comment: falla con cualquier fecha, en la linea 138

Comment: Decir el numero de linea no es muy util para nosotros ... y la info extra ha de ir en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Comment: modifica la pregunta y pon el codigo completo, incluyo la declaracion de variables, por lo que parece es que la fecha no esta "seteada"... pero hazle caso a lois... debes ser mas claro con la pregunta :D

Comment: Puedes indicar cual es la linea 138? .. y creo que el xml es innecesario en esta pregunta

Comment: A mi parecer tu error esta aqui: ´fechanacimiento = LocalDate.parse(campo7.getText());´, podria ser falta de ´toString()´ o que la entrada en ese campo sea incorrecta, revisa eso.

Comment: Aunque el error es lanzado por null exception, aseguras el valor de los campos?

Comment: lois he indicado arriba la linea exacta del error.

Comment: denifer lo he probado con el to string y me sigue saliendo el mismo error y estoy poniendo la fecha con formato " 1997-08-10", he probado a debugear y me aparecen los datos correctos a la hora de añadir el contacto

Comment: Tu error es sencillo de ver, no inicializas contactos en el constructor de Contacto, así que cuando haces contacto.contactos.add(contacto); estás intentando añadir algo a un array que es null. Inicializa el array en el constructor de Contacto y listo, a funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que dices se debe a que no has inicializado el ArrayList de la clase Contacto, debes poner el constructor de la siguiente manera:

```
public Contacto(String nombre, String papellido, String sapellido, String direccion, String poblacion, int foto, Integer telefono, LocalDate fechanacimiento) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.papellido = papellido;
    this.sapellido = sapellido;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.poblacion = poblacion;
    this.foto = foto;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento;
    contactos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta ;)

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta cuando ejecutas el método add del ArrayList de contactos, cuando instancias el objeto Contacto, no instancias automáticamente la lista, es decir que aun diciendo New Contacto la lista estará en null y por lo tanto te arrojara un error al querer usar uno de sus métodos.

Puedes hacer encapsulamiento (get() y set()) al ArrayList e inicializarla con setContactos(new ArrayList) y de este modo ya podrás utilizar el método add.

Recuerda que cada vez que Inicies la lista se borraran todos los datos que tengas almacenados ahi, por lo tanto es recomendable inicializar la lista solo una vez en todo el proceso.

Comment: He intentado con contacto.setContactos(new ArrayList<Contacto>()); crear un array para despues meter alli los contactos que vaya añadiendo pero me da un error de null object reference, como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Utiliza solo el new ArrayList<>(); sin hacer referencia a un objeto.